# Find the duplicate values of first column present in second column and return the corresponding row number of the value in second column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two columns in a dataframe with overlapping values.How to find the duplicate values of first column present in the second column and return the corresponding row number of the value in second column in a new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pandas.compat import StringIO
print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""a,b
111,122
122,3
111,9
254,395
265,245
111,395
220,111
395,305
395,8""")
df1 = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")

# find unique duplicate values in first column
col_a_dups = df1['a'][df1['a'].duplicated()].unique()
corresponding_value = df1['b'][df1['b'].isin(col_a_dups)]
print(df1.join(corresponding_value, lsuffix="_l", rsuffix="_r"))
#print(corresponding_value.index)
```

Produces

```
0.24.2
     a  b_l    b_r
0  111  122    NaN
1  122    3    NaN
2  111    9    NaN
3  254  395  395.0
4  265  245    NaN
5  111  395  395.0
6  220  111  111.0
7  395  305    NaN
8  395    8    NaN
```

Comment: Many thanks @Rich Andrews. The answers is right. How to return the corresponding row number of the value in second column in a new column in the dataframe ?

Comment: A simple join of the original dataframe and the resultant matches in column b will do the trick.  My answer is updated to demonstrate that.  If it solves your problem, don't forget to accept the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rich Andrews